# Internal expansion with the find command and wildcard character

Tags: shell, find, quoting, wildcards

I'm still learning the command line and I am having some trouble fully understanding the use of the wildcard within the find command.

I'm working in the directory user/temp and use the find command as followed to find all .txt files:

```
find . -name *.txt -print
```

This gives me the error:

```
find: unknown primary or operator.
```

I know you need to use single quotes around the `*.txt` in order to escape the expansion and get your desired result; however, I do not understand why this needs to be done.

I read that you have to escape the `*` so that `find` does the expansion internally. I am confused because I thought that using single quotes around `*` will give make the command line not interpret it as a special character, so how does the expansion take place?

Comment: I formatted the code parts for you, and added a `*` into the first find command, if you didn't mean that to be there obviously remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 parts here that could try to expand the `*`: the shell when it's invoking `find` or `find` as it's processing/using its arguments.

If you do not single quote it, the shell will expand it, so if you have a.txt and b.txt in the current directory your command line would expand from

```
find . -name *.txt -print
```

to

```
find . -name a.txt b.txt -print
```

which isn't a valid `find` command

If you single quote it, you will tell the shell to leave it alone, so `find` will get the string `*.txt` as the argument to `-name` and it will use it as when matching potential names.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up for me and formatting the code! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try double quoting the file name.

> find . -name "*.txt" -print

That works on my system (Debian 8)